# Show content area for qualified rows from lookup function in AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

I want to show the content area, on checking how many records are having `meetingdate` greater then today. below is my code. In my code, no content areas are showing. Don't know where I went wrong.

```
%%[
SET @Count=0
Set @rs = LookupOrderedRows("Res_InfoMeeting_tst",5,"MeetingDate Asc","MeetingType","on") 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rs)

if @rowCount > 0 then
    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

        SET @row = Row(@rs,@i)
        SET @meetingDate = field(@row,"MeetingDate")
        SET @MeetingID = field(@row,"MeetingID")
        Set @MeetingURL = CONCAT('http://www.ef.pl/ils/infomeetings/v3/?infomeetingId=',@MeetingID)

        if(@meetingDate > Now()) Then
            SET @Count1=Add(@Count,1)
            if (@Count1==1)Then
            %%=ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Dynamic Content - test\ranjith_test-1")=%%<br/><br/>
            elseif(@Count1==2)Then
            %%=ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Dynamic Content - test\ranjith_test-2")=%%<br/><br/>
            elseif(@Count1==3)Then
            %%=ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Dynamic Content - test\ranjith_test-3")=%%<br/><br/>
            elseif(@Count1==4)Then
            %%=ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Dynamic Content - test\ranjith_test-4")=%%<br/><br/>
            elseif(@Count1==5)Then
            %%=ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Dynamic Content - test\ranjith_test-5")=%%<br/><br/>
            endif
        ]%%
        %%[
        endif
    next @i
else
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    content-4
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
endif
]%%
%%=v(@Count1)=%%
```

Comment: You should call your first if variables before you call the else .

Comment: Count1 isn't set to a content area

Answer (score 1):

You're not closing your AMPScript blocks properly.  You can't output raw HTML inside the `%%[ ]%%` tags.

```
%%[

SET @Count = 0
Set @rs = LookupOrderedRows("Res_InfoMeeting_tst",5,"MeetingDate Asc","MeetingType","on") 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rs)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

        SET @row = Row(@rs,@i)

        SET @meetingDate = field(@row,"MeetingDate")
        SET @MeetingID = field(@row,"MeetingID")
        Set @MeetingURL = CONCAT('URL',@MeetingID)

        if (@meetingDate > Now()) Then

            SET @Count = Add(@Count,1)

            if (@Count == 1) Then
                 SET @showcontent = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Dynamic Content - test\test_content-1")
            elseif (@Count == 2) Then
                  SET @showcontent = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Dynamic Content - test\test_content-2")
            elseif (@Count == 3) Then
                  SET @showcontent = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Dynamic Content - test\test_content-3")
            elseif (@Count == 4) Then
                  SET @showcontent = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Dynamic Content - test\test_content-4")
            elseif (@Count == 5) Then
                   SET @showcontent =  ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Dynamic Content - test\test_content-5")
            endif

            output(treatascontent(@showcontent))

        endif

    next @i
else
]%%
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            content-4
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
%%[endif]%%
%%=v(@Count)=%%
```

The [**treatascontent()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/treatascontent.htm) function will ensure any AMPScript in your content areas will be evaluated.